# Heroku logging for django management commands

Tags: django, heroku, logging

I would like to log statements when running a Django management command on Heroku.

So, for example, when I login to Heroku and run the command:

```
heroku run bash
python manage.py my_management_command
```

I should see all of the logging.info statements included.  But instead they don't appear in the Heroku logs.  All logging.info statements from the normal django appear fine, just not when I run a management command.

My logger setup in settings.py is as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        },
    },
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get log statements from inside my django management command to appear in the heroku logs?

Comment: This is by design. Are the management commands you're talking about ones that you need to interact with manually, or are they things you're trying to schedule or otherwise run unattended?